# Need help in installing numpy

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, installation

I tried to install numpy but I got this error:

> pip install numpy --user
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/quadro2/adil_env/bin/pip", line 7, in 
> from pip._internal.cli.main import main
> File "/home/quadro2/adil_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
> sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you try using `pip3 install numpy`?